# want to create cron job from the command line

Tags: php, mysql, csv, cron

i have built a CMS website that replies upon the mysql records of a 3rd party. i intend to download the 3rd party records via CSV. i then want to use a Cron job via my command line to update my mysql records

i know how to manually upload to mysql via CSV i.e:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'c:/tmp/discounts_2.csv'INTO TABLE discountsFIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'IGNORE 1 ROWS(title,@expired_date,amount)SET expired_date = STR_TO_DATE(@expired_date, '%m/%d/%Y');
```

however, i am not sure how to go about creating a cron job that will automtically link to the command line and then perform this function.

i guess that what i want is a pointer on how i can go about doing this.

UPDATE 
@fancyPants asked the question "what do i want the cronJob to do?"
the answer is this. i want the cronJob job to access the CSV file (that i have previously downloaded)
and then upload all those values from the CSV file to the mysql database

i know the  command for doing the CSV conversion to mysql;

> LOAD DATA INFILE 'c:/tmp/discounts_2.csv'INTO TABLE discountsFIELDS
>   TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'IGNORE 1
>   ROWS(title,@expired_date,amount)SET expired_date =
>   STR_TO_DATE(@expired_date, '%m/%d/%Y');

i am however stuck at the point of how to do a cron job to my command line and then how to execute the above command once the cron arrives at the command line

Comment: You want the cronjob to do what exactly?

Comment: hello fancyPants. i want the cron job to essentially access the cvs file and then to upload the values of the CSV file to the mysql table

Answer (score 0):

Create a MySQL event rather than a cronjob.

Enable the event scheduler with

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
```

and create an event like this:

```
DELIMITER $
CREATE EVENT 
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY
STARTS '2015-10-11 00:00:00'
DO
BEGIN
TRUNCATE TABLE discounts;
LOAD DATA INFILE 'c:/tmp/discounts_2.csv'INTO TABLE discounts FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'IGNORE 1 ROWS(title,@expired_date,amount)SET expired_date = STR_TO_DATE(@expired_date, '%m/%d/%Y');
END $
DELIMITER ;
```

and that's it.

Read more about the syntax [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-event.html) and [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html) is more general information about it.

Comment: hey fancyPants. thanks for that advise. i will look into it. two  quick question. should i delete the previous data in the table first. (my fear is that if i have to delete the information first, the site will not work for the duration of the data transfer

Comment: in other words how do u get around the issue of updating your database during a CSV transfer when lots of the information in the database will change. do you simple delete the database and upload from fresh or do we do an update

Comment: Yes, truncate table first is probably your best bet. For multiple statements in the event you have to adjust the syntax a bit. Edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: hey FancyPants.Thanks so much for hour help-quick and final question. where do i go in my mysqlAdmin to create this command